# Articles.video_post/0 is undefined when adding new view Phoenix 1.3 app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to add a page to a site that will only show posts that contain `video` in a field called `postType` in my `articles_posts` table but I get the error saying the function is undefined.

In my articles context **articles.ex**

```
  def video_post do
    Post |> where(postType: "video")|> Repo.all()
  end
```

**video_controller**

```
defmodule Driverless.Web.VideoController do
  use Driverless.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    videoposts = Articles.video_post()
    render(conn, "index.html", videoposts: videoposts)
  end
end
```

And in the view i'm using `<%= for post <- @videoposts do %>`

I get the same error even when I add in the standard `posts = Articles.list_posts()`

Can't spot what's going on here.

Comment: Missing `alias Driverless.Articles` in `Driverless.Web.VideoController`?

Comment: Yep!  That was it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dogbert do you mind if I upgrade your comment to an answer for you?